# How to access a specific component in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok, I'm trying to access a boxcollider2d from within a collision callback like that:

```
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        col.collider.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().sharedMaterial.friction = 0;
    }
```

But first it doesn't work (the propoerty is null) and second how would I do if I had two boxcollider2d ?

What is the right method ?

Thanks

Comment: The collider property is null or there is no BoxCollider2D returned? (p.s. isn't your collider the BoxCollider2D?)

Comment: Why are you Getting the component BoxCollider2D? col.collider should already be that collider. Also, if you had two BoxCollider2D's both would hit the OnCollisionEnter2D function and both would send the appropriate Collision2D (so long as their hitbox collide with the other colliders hitbox).

Comment: the sharedMaterial is null, however I assigned a material in the collider...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Collision2D documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision2D.html) the .collider property is

> The incoming Collider2D involved in the collision.

Which means that it's the actual component (BoxCollider2D, CircleCollider2D, PolygonCollider2D or EdgeCollider2D) that you collided with.

So try removing the GetComponent and see what you get. If you really want to use GetComponent (not recommended if not needed) you can use the `col.gameObject` to get the GameObject and from there use `col.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()`.

If there are multiple Components you will get an array of components. This might be your problem, you'd have to specify which of the components you want with: `col.gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>()[0]`. But if you choose the `col.collider` you should get the collider that you actually touched in your collision.

Comment: I removed the getComponent but the sharedmaterial is still null.

Comment: Have you ensured the collider have a physics material? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-sharedMaterial.html